# How to download a file using wget or curl

Tags: curl, csv, wget

I'm not been able to find a way to download a csv file from http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=XOM+BBDb.TO+JNJ+MSFT&f=snd1l1yr

using wget or curl ,it downloads a file but the contents are not inside it.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
curl -L 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=XOM+BBDb.TO+JNJ+MSFT&f=snd1l1yr' > joy.csv
```